# Para que sirve obtener una direccion de memoria

Tags: c++, punteros

Estoy aprendiendo sobre los punteros y básicamente comprendí que tienen 2 funciones:

1. "Reflejar" el valor de una variable (no tiene más complicación).
2. Arrojar la dirección de memoria de una variable.

¿Para qué quisiera saber la dirección de memoria de una variable? ¿Para qué sirve?

Answer (score 4):

Muy buenas, pues los punteros son algo super fundamental para el paso por referencia. Para empezar debes saber la diferencia entre ambos. Con el paso por valor lo que haces es hacer una copia de dicha variable y por mucho que modifiques el valor en una función de la copia, la variable original tendrá el mismo valor. Sin embargo el paso por referencia tú no aplicas cambios en la copia, si no que realizas cambios sobre la variable original.

Aquí entran los punteros en juego, a la hora de modificar un dato de un struct en una función, es fundamental el uso de & y *.

Con el & lo que haces es pasar la dirección de memoria de la variable. Digamos que lo que haces es darle la llave de la casa de tu variable a una función, para así poder modificarla. Pero claro, en la función tendrás que utilizar el *, digamos que el * es abrir la puerta con la llave y saber usarla.

Por tanto, siempre en el main vas a pasar &NombreVariable que quieras modificar y en la funcion pondrás *NombreVariable. Y es fundamental que operes con el *.
Te dejo un pequeño programa de ejemplo para que veas como en c++, siempre se pasan los parámetros por valor(otros lenguajes de programación usan por defecto el paso por referencia).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
void noIntercambia(int a,int b){
    int aux=a;
    a=b;
    b=aux;
}
void intercambia(int *a,int *b){
    int aux=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=aux;
}
int main() {
    int a=5,b=3;
    noIntercambia(a,b);//PASO POR VALOR
    cout<<"Datos no se cambian: "<<a<<b<<endl;
    intercambia(&a,&b);//PASO POR REFERENCIA
    cout<<"Datos se cambian: "<<a<<b<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Esto muestra por pantalla:

```
Datos no se cambian: 53
Datos se cambian:35
```

Ya sabes la importancia que tiene saber usar punteros y direcciones de memoria, espero haberte aclarado tu duda.Un saludo.